# Change sorting in view while allowing users to sort the view too

Tags: 2010, view, sorting

One of our customers asked to sort a document library based on the last modify date, so the last updated file is on top. 
However, when I change the view and add sorting, this will prevent the users to change the sorting and find a document quickly by its name.
Is there an option to set the default sorting to the "modified" column and still give the possibility to end users to sort the list otherwise if needed?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood. But the user can click over the column titles to sort.

Comment: Yes, but the initial order of the files is by ID, so the last file added is the last in the list. Would be better to have something else as default that makes  more sense like ABC or date.

Comment: Perhaps you could create more than one view...